# Hidden parameter in springdoc-openapi doesn't work

Tags: spring-boot, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

I have Spring Boot application with version 2.3.0. 
and springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui in version 1.4.1.

I have annotated parameter in operation like this.

```
parameters = {
@Parameter(
    hidden = true, schema = @Schema(implementation = Boolean.class),
    in = ParameterIn.QUERY, name = DO_NOT_FORWARD
)
```

With **hidden = true** I expected that this parameter will not be visible in swagger-ui. But it is. 
Did I misunderstood this parameter or is it not doing what it was supposed to do?

I want this parameter to be in api-docs, to have generated client able to use this parameter, but I want it invisible in swagger-ui

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of the method? The Current piece of code doesn't convey a proper sense of where and how you're using it

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
@Parameter(name = "paramName", hidden = true)
@GetMapping("/example")
public Object example(String paramName) {
    return null;
}
```

instead of

```
@Operation(
    parameters = {
        @Parameter(name = "paramName", hidden = true)
    }
)
@GetMapping("/example")
public Object example(String paramName) {
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just make sure that the name of in the @Parameter annotation, is the exact name of the operation parameter you want to hide.

You can have a look at the documentation as well:

- https://springdoc.org/faq.html#how-can-i-hide-a-parameter-from-the-documentation-

If you are still having coniguration issue, you can add the code of sample HelloController that reproduces your problem, or you can add the link to a minimal, reproducible sample in github.

Comment: Do you have a working code example? It's still not working for me. I will try to post my code or create sample

Answer (score 0):

As per the [doc](https://springdoc.org/faq.html#_how_can_i_hide_a_parameter_from_the_documentation)

```
@GetMapping("/example")
fun someCall: Response (
@Parameter(hidden = true) String paramName
) {
    return response;
}
```